# Why is my kernel not seeing usb devices on boot

Tags: linux

I am currently booting a kernel off of a usb pen drive. The issue I am having is that once it starts booting the kernel, it cannot see the usb pen (itself) to boot the filesystem. I have tried setting the filesystem by UUIDs, SDB1, set boot delays—all of that. The annoying thing is that it works fine when there isn't an SSD in the machine but for the purpose of my R&D, the SSD has to be in there while it boots 100% off the pen.

Any help and/or ideas?

Comment: Distribution? Std-kernel, or rolled your own? Is USB support present in the kernel at all?

Comment: rolled my own, using the latest kernel for kernel.org, yes usb support is present